# React 15.4.2 Cannot read property 'ref' of null

Tags: reactjs

I try get access to method of child component.
It look like that:
1.Called method by ref name of component and then method

**Form.js**

```
this.ref.details.getDataFromComponent();
    <Details
        pointToShow={this.state.point}
        ref="details"
    />
```

**Details.js**

```
getDataFromComponent() {
  //do my stuff get state and connect to get data for component Details
}
```

All the time I have "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of null"
React 15.4.2

Comment: Show us where you define the `details` ref

Comment: `//do my stuff get state and connect to get data for component Details` ... At least some of this would probably be useful

Answer (score 1):

To access refs of a component, you need to use `this.refs`, not `this.ref`.

However, this does not seem to be the issue here, as the error clearly says that `this` is `null` when you are trying to access it. To determine why this is we need to see more of your code.

---

You should also look into defining refs using the [ref callback attribute](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#the-ref-callback-attribute) instead of the way you are doing it, as this syntax is no longer recommended and may be removed in future releases.

Comment: Thanks that is my sollution and additional i should add one method to constructor with binding

Answer (score 0):

As Timo has mentioned to access an element using  `refs` you should you should write `this.refs...`

According to the error you don't have access to `this`. Most probably you are calling `this.ref.details.getDataFromComponent();` inside a method without access to `this`

For example you write :

```
callRef() {
  this.ref.details.getDataFromComponent();
  ....
}
```

If so then you don't have an access to `this` there. You should bind your function with `this`.
You can either use arrow function to auto bind with `this` :

```
callRef = () => {
  this.ref.details.getDataFromComponent();
  ....
}
```

Note: to use arrow function you need to use babel loader in your webpack configuration.

Or you can bind when calling the method.
For example you should call `callRef()` method inside jsx codes like this:

```
< ... onClick={this.callRef.bind(this)} />
```